# Probleme with Font on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, uppercase, google-font-api

I have a problem with a font in firefox. There is a height difference between the letters and the letters are distorted.

Please check this page (look at the artist name) : http://www.fipradio.fr/archives-antenne

On my computer the characters appear as they are on this image :
[image]

In this case the font name is : "Montserrat".

I encounter the problem when I assign the following properties:

```css
#myText {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Who can give me a way to solve this problem ?

Thankz by advance,

Mickaël

Comment: One possible reason could be that the font `Montserrat` you added doesn't have a `font-weight: 800` version. So its browser who is trying to convert `normal` to `bold`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using google fonts, use the following link to include normal and bold variants of the font

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then for your style make the following changes:

```
#myText {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

Good luck, have fun!

Comment: Yes I use Google font. I've tried your solution but It does not work. I've the problem only where the font-size is under 20px

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by using "CSS3 font-size-adjust" property (only for mozilla)

[CSS3 font-size-adjust Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-size-adjust.asp)

Thankz